# Usort sort multidimensional array by continuing values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, usort

I have an array:

```
$cards = [
    [
        "from" => "Barcelona",
        "to" => "Gerona Airport",        
    ],
    [
        "from" => "Stockholm",
        "to" => "New York JFK",          
    ],
    [
        "from" => "Gerona Airport",
        "to" => "Stockholm",          
    ],
    [
        "from" => "Madrid",
        "to" => "Barcelona",          
    ]
];
```

I need to sort it to make a continuing trip, where the `from` matches the previous `to`, or be set as the start if not, like:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array ( [from] => Madrid [to] => Barcelona )  
    [1] => Array ( [from] => Barcelona [to] => Gerona Airport )
    [2] => Array ( [from] => Gerona Airport [to] => Stockholm ) 
    [3] => Array ( [from] => Stockholm [to] => New York JFK ) 
)
```

I am trying to use `usort`:

```
usort($cards, function ($a, $b) {
          return ( $a["to"] === $b["from"] ) ? -1 : 1;
      });

print_r($cards);
```

But it's does not sort in the manner described. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you going to know which one of those arrays is the beginning of the trip?

Comment: no it doesn't matter, the point is to sort the array to make a Continuing trip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully a better solution will come along, but if you sort as many times as there are elements in the array and return equal or greater then it works; even if you don't know the beginning or if the beginning is not the first element. Because of the way `usort` traverses and compares, returning equal or less does not work:

```
foreach($cards as $card) {
    usort($cards, function ($a, $b) {
                      return ( $a["to"] === $b["from"] ) ? 0 : 1;
                  });
}
```

It may work with fewer iterations, but comparing each against all others seems safe.

Comment: Thanks @Syscall .  Your original seemed to work, but I shuffled the array and it was hit or miss.

Comment: Really nice answer :) You got my +1 ! I've tested mine by adding many other cities, shuffled too, and seems to work (I'll test it again), but yours is better!

Comment: I was searching for something like that :)

Answer (score 1):

You might take a recursive approach and specify the city to start from.

By default, you start at Madrid with `doSort($cards, $result);`.

If you want to get the continuing trip from "Gerona Airport", you could start it with `doSort($cards, $result, "Gerona Airport");`

```
$cards = [
    [
        "from" => "Barcelona",
        "to" => "Gerona Airport",
    ],
    [
        "from" => "Stockholm",
        "to" => "New York JFK",
    ],
    [
        "from" => "Gerona Airport",
        "to" => "Stockholm",
    ],
    [
        "from" => "Madrid",
        "to" => "Barcelona",
    ]
];
$result = [];

function doSort($cards, &$result, $start = "Madrid") {
    foreach ($cards as $key => $card) {
        if ($card["from"] === $start) {
            $result[] = $card;
            doSort($cards, $result, $card["to"]);
        }
    }
}
doSort($cards, $result);
print_r($result);
```

[Php output demo](https://3v4l.org/IFF8A)

That will give you:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [from] => Madrid
            [to] => Barcelona
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [from] => Barcelona
            [to] => Gerona Airport
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [from] => Gerona Airport
            [to] => Stockholm
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [from] => Stockholm
            [to] => New York JFK
        )

)
```

Comment: I tried with a longer shuffled array and this seems to work well.

Answer (score 0):

here is a way. Finding the start, and search the path, by iteration :

```
// 1. Find the start
$start = null;
$starts = array_column($cards,'from');
$ends = array_column($cards,'to');
foreach ($cards as $card) {
    if (!in_array($card['from'], $ends)) $start=$card;
}
// 2. Find way
$way=[$start];
while (count($cards)>1) {
    $found = false ;
    foreach ($cards as $k => $card) {
        if ($card['from'] == $start['to']) {
            $way[] = $card;
            $start = $card;
            unset($cards[$k]);
            $found = true ;
            break 1;
        }
    }
    if (!$found) { echo "Impossible to use all cards.\n" ; break ; }
}
print_r($way);
```

Outputs:

```
    Array (
    [0] => Array ([from] => Madrid [to] => Barcelona )
    [1] => Array ([from] => Barcelona [to] => Gerona Airport )
    [2] => Array ([from] => Gerona Airport [to] => Stockholm )
    [3] => Array ([from] => Stockholm [to] => New York JFK )
)
```